# Showing cookie alert after a delay

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I found a good example of using cookie alert based on bootstrap. I am trying to amend the code and use it as a form to ask user to rank a page/website.

```
<div id="cookie-alert" data-expire="30" class="alert alert-primary alert-position-bottom">
    <div class="container">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
            <span class="cookie-close-btn" aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>

        <p class="fs-13">
            <i class="fa fa-warning"></i> 

            We use cookies to provide you with a better service. 
            Carry on browsing if you're happy with this, or find out how to 
            <a href="#">manage cookies</a>.
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to show it after a delay 5-10 mins or after a number of visits of a specific page?

i found the code here:
https://theme.stepofweb.com/Smarty/v2.1.0/HTML_BS4/page-cookie-alert.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a simple example. Add the following to the file.

CSS:

```
#cookie-alert{
            display:none;
        }
```

JS:

```
(function(){
        setTimeout(showAlert, 2000)
    })();


    function showAlert()
    {
    document.getElementById("cookie-alert").style.display = "block";
    }
```

Change the time to whatever you'd like. Keep in mind that this is just a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

To show that message with a delay you can use something simple like this:

```
// Vanilla JS to show it after period of time
var cookieDiv = document.getElementById('cookie-alert');
cookieDiv.style.display = 'none';

setTimeout(function(){
    cookieDiv.style.display='block';
},5000) // Show it after 5000ms
```

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cgn6qj98/2/